# How to login to facebook using the Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'd like to post messages to a group wall without asking user for login information -I'd like to do it programmatically, I can use my user/pass if necessary-.

¿Is it possible to do this without showing the user the login screen?

Note: I'm working with Facebook C# SDK (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) under ASP.NET.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot do this. Facebook prevents this sort of behavior to prevent spamming on peoples walls from fake accounts. You will always have to go through the initial login procedure AT LEAST ONCE.

However, if you get an offline access token for someone then you could continue to make posts from them when they are not logged in. Keep in mind that Facebook limits you to 600 posts per minute.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the answer to this is "No you can't" If I have a valid ID and password can't I log into the account behind the scenes? I'm needing to write a windows service or console app that runs on a prescribed schedule.

Comment: He is right.  The accepted way to do this is to get the offline_access extended permission and save the resulting session key for later use.  Now that we know Facebook supports this, I too am interested in how to make offline calls to the Facebook api from a console app with this SDK.  Anyone?  The samples seem to all expect you to log in via a browser control.

Comment: If it is possible to do this and go through the manual login process once, I'd love to see code demonstrating how to achieve it. My needs are to run facebook integrations tests via NUnit, which will be done at build-time to verify no regressions creep in. It also helps when the API goes down every once in awhile so we know to expect "user feedback."