# Using the Facebook C# SDK from NUnit

Tags: c#, facebook, nunit

Are there any code samples that work that allow the Facebook SDK to authenticate and to be able to get likes and other data? Idea being that, I'd like to have a unit test to run in conjunction with a continously integrated environment. I don't want to have to use a browser to do it. Might not be possible, I guess.

Comment: The real question here is, why are you doing Facebook's job by testing their SDK?

Comment: Because they don't offer an SLA (AFAIK), so I like knowing when it isn't online. Nice to know when the flood is about to hit.

Comment: If you're testing facebook's liveliness, just hit the URI and see if you get a response.

Comment: sometimes API's evolve, and those evolutions can cause breaking changes. I'd like to know when that occurs. I guess I'll just drop it and appreciate incomplete coverage and remove the clients who have a desire to do this sort of thing out-of-browser from my list of potentials business partners, seems this is too brittle a thing, or I'm not thinking about it properly.

Comment: I'll try re-stating the question since the mention of NUnit has derailed all sense of logic and patience. I simply want non-browser access to user data, of users who've signed up for the app. I felt a NUnit test would provide guidance as I solved the issue. I've tried to close this question since I asked it in a manner that obviously caused some disdain and confusion. My apologies.

Comment: @bradygaster: Just edit the question to more accurately reflect what you want. There are no downvotes and only one close vote. Don't post a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

this is a case where you will want to avoid testing this dependency ... as you suggest, it becomes far too difficult to test when there's a browser/user in the workflow. So you want to properly abstract this away from your testable logic, and simply use a mock object

Comment: Not an option, so I'll continue investigating. Without this I'd lack 100% coverage. Plus, I have other things I'd like to use the functionality for in non-browser application exercises. The nature of testing this - as in it isn't in a browser window - emulates the nature of the application in which I'll be using it.

Comment: Appears as though it is at least partially possible. See answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344666/how-to-login-to-facebook-using-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273425/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-problem-getting-an-access-token for details.

Comment: First or all, Joel is right. Not because he's got 13k+ reputation, but simply because he's right. This is a case where you want to avoid testing this dependency. You should be wrapping Facebook's SDK in some kind of interface, so that you can mock out that interface for use when testing. If you DON'T do it this way, your application's unit tests will fail every time you add or remove a friend, like or dislike something, etc. This is a dependency NIGHTMARE. Instead, abstract facebook away from your application so that you can test your application without relying on Facebook's service.

Comment: Joel is correct but only for testing business logic. At some point you may want to test your implementation of the abstraction. I think that is the challenge here.